# cartopy doesnt fill country even though fillcolor is set

Tags: python, cartopy

I would like to highlight a country by filling it with the color red. However, when I do so following examples such as this one: https://matthewkudija.com/blog/2018/05/25/country-maps/

It doesn't work. Instead, it just plots the original color. It only seems to work when I use the `PlateCarree` projection.

```
import cartopy
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
from cartopy.mpl.gridliner import LONGITUDE_FORMATTER, LATITUDE_FORMATTER
import cartopy.io.shapereader as shpreader
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 10))

proj = ccrs.Orthographic(50, 30)
ax = plt.axes(projection=proj)

ax.add_feature(cartopy.feature.OCEAN, zorder=0)
ax.add_feature(cartopy.feature.LAND, zorder=0, edgecolor='black')

ax.set_global()
ax.gridlines()
ax.add_feature(cartopy.feature.BORDERS, linestyle=':', alpha=1)

shpfilename = shpreader.natural_earth(resolution='110m',
                                      category='cultural',
                                      name='admin_0_countries')
reader = shpreader.Reader(shpfilename)
countries = reader.records()

for country in countries:
    if country.attributes['ADM0_A3'] == 'OMN':
        break
ax.add_geometries(country.geometry, proj,
                  # facecolor=(1, 0, 0),
                  facecolor='red',
                  # label=country.attributes['adm0_a3'])
                  label=country.attributes['ADM0_A3']
                 ,zorder=20)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there a specific reason you need the crs to be set to Orthographic? As you said, the code ran successfully for me using

```
import cartopy
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
from cartopy.mpl.gridliner import LONGITUDE_FORMATTER, LATITUDE_FORMATTER
import cartopy.io.shapereader as shpreader
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 10))

proj = ccrs.Orthographic(50, 30)
ax = plt.axes(projection=proj)

ax.add_feature(cartopy.feature.OCEAN, zorder=0)
ax.add_feature(cartopy.feature.LAND, zorder=0, edgecolor='black')

ax.set_global()
ax.gridlines()
ax.add_feature(cartopy.feature.BORDERS, linestyle=':', alpha=1)

shpfilename = shpreader.natural_earth(resolution='110m',
                                      category='cultural',
                                      name='admin_0_countries')
reader = shpreader.Reader(shpfilename)
countries = reader.records()

for country in countries:
    if country.attributes['ADM0_A3'] == 'OMN':
        ax.add_geometries(country.geometry, ccrs.PlateCarree(), facecolor='red')
```

[image]

Comment: yeah this github issue explains why https://github.com/SciTools/cartopy/issues/1996